# Redirect to file as well as to STDOUT in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I've a long bash script with multiple `echo` statements.

I had a requirement to redirect bash script's output to a file without using redirection from bash shell. I could accomplish that by doing:

```
exec 1>>/tmp/output
```

How do I do something like both redirecting to a file and not stopping to output in STDOUT?

I don't want to edit each and every echo statement to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the help from #bash IRC.

```
exec > >(tee file)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`tee`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee)

```
your_script | tee /tmp/output
```

Comment: I specifically asked for `I had a requirement to redirect bash script's output to a file without using redirection from bash shell.` Anyways, I got it on how to do it but can't delete the question now. `exec > >(tee file)`

Comment: Your requirement is confusing.  Piping is arguably different from redirection.  Anyway, glad you got it worked out.